Proving $\sinh^{-1}x=-i\sin^{-1}ix$
I discovered this relation while playing around with $\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$.
Method 1:
This is a standard integral, so it can be directly written as:
$$\int\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}=\sinh^{-1}x+C$$
Method 2:
The integrand can be rewritten in the form $\frac1{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$ if $t=\pm ix\left(i=\sqrt{-1}\right)$. For simplicity, I took $t=ix$. Here, I have made the assumption that the domain of the function $\sin^{-1}x$ can be extended to $\mathbb C$:
$$-i\int\frac{\mathrm d(ix)}{\sqrt{1-(ix)^2}}=-i\sin^{-1}ix+C$$
So, $\sinh^{-1}x$ and $-i\sin^{-1}ix$ differ by a constant:
$$\sinh^{-1}x=-i\sin^{-1}ix+C$$
To find $C$, I put $x=0$ in the above equation:
$$0=0+C$$
$$\therefore \sinh^{-1}x=-i\sin^{-1}ix$$
But since this did not seem like a rigorous proof of the formula, I tried to use the relation $\sinh x=-i\sin{ix}$ to prove it:
$$\text{Let }y=\sinh^{-1}x\implies x=\sinh y \text{ as} \sinh x \text{ is a bijective function }\forall x\in \mathbb R$$
$$\implies x=-i\sin iy$$
$$\implies ix=\sin iy$$
$$\implies \sin^{-1}ix=\sin^{-1}\sin iy$$
This is where I got stuck. I had no clue how to evaluate $\sin^{-1}\sin x$ for imaginary values of $x$. I know how to do it for real $x$, but I am not familiar with working with inverse trigonometric functions when their domain is extended to $\mathbb C$. Can someone suggest me how to proceed forward? Or is there any other way to prove this?
I tried to look up my query on this site, but could not find any relevant post. If someone does find such a post, kindly share it by commenting before downvoting without any explanation. I was able to find these links on Quora, but both of them implicitly used $\sin^{-1}\sin ix=ix, x\in\mathbb R$.

probably need to start from definition 2 in here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Inverse_Sine/Complex, and work out if you can constraint to one branch only for your particular integral.

Do you know that $i\sin(z) = \sinh(iz)$ for all complex numbers $z$?

Those who have doubts or require any clarification, please comment before downvoting.

@MartinR yes I do, it directly comes from $\sinh x=-i\sin ix=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}2$. I am familiar with taking sine, cosine,etc. of complex numbers since the trig ratios of imaginary numbers obtained on applying compound angle formulae can be expressed via hyperbolic functions.

@zwim thanks, that helped me complete the proof. But where did this formula come from? Or is it simply defined that way?

Why the downvote? Please explain.

Please cut down on minor edits, @MathGuy.

Let
$$
\sinh^{−1}x = y, \tag{1}
$$
and
$$
-i\sin^{-1}ix = z. \tag{2}
$$
Now I will try to prove $y = z$.
From (2),
$$
\Rightarrow \sin^{-1}ix=-\frac{z}{i} \\
\Rightarrow ix=\sin(-\frac{z}{i})=\frac{e^{-z}-e^z}{2i} \\
\Rightarrow x=\frac{e^{z}-e^{-z}}{2}=\sinh z \\
\Rightarrow z=\sinh^{-1}x=y.
$$
Thus proved.

Does $\sin(\sin^{-1} x)=x$ hold for any imaginary value of $x$? Is it obtained by extrapolating this relation for $x\in [-1,1]$?

Or, in other words, is $\sin^{-1}x$ a bijective function from $\mathbb C-\mathbb R\to \mathbb C-\mathbb R$?

Could be, if the branch cut is selected correctly. If the branch cuts for inverse $\sinh$ and $\sin$ are both selected to be the same , say $[-\pi, \pi]$, then everything is fine here.

Can you please explain branch cut in simple terms? On the internet, it is explained using the terms singularities, analytic function which I am not able to understand since I am in high school.

Without branch cut, $\sin^{-1}x$ is multi-valued. Say $x=1$, then $\sin^{-1}x=-\pi/2, \pi/2, 3\pi/2, \cdots $. Selecting a branch $(-\pi, \pi]$ means to accept only values in the range $(-\pi, \pi]$ as the function value of $\sin^{-1}x$.

Ok thank you, I got it!

@MathGuy The branch cut also explains why there is an extra constant $C$ in your method 1. If you don't choose a branch cut, with the same example $x=1$, $\sin^{−1}x=−π/2,π/2,3π/2,\cdots=-\pi/2 + n\pi$, the term $n\pi$ here is the integration constant $C$.
